# Binding a string variable to a label

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to move from WinForms to WPF, and am stuck on binding.

I have a label:

```
    <Label Name="labelState" Content="{Binding state}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="12" />
```

In the cs of the same userControl (named FormInput), I have :

```
 public string state { get; set; }

  public FormInput()
        {
            state = "ok";

            InitializeComponent();          
        }
```

Why doesn't this work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are binding something in WPF you need to use **`INotifyPropertyChanged`**

Implement a class follows,

```
class TestObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _state;

        public string State
        {
            get
            {
                return _state;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_state == value) return;

                _state = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("State");
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

and in your **`FormInput`**

```
public FormInput()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  TestObject t = new TestObject();
  labelState.DataContext = t;
  t.State = "ok";
}
```

and XAML as follows,

```
  <Label Name="labelState" Content="{Binding State}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"    >
```

Comment: This won't work because state has no dependency property or INotifyPropertyChanged-Pattern. So changes won't propagate after initialisation. But InitializeComponent should take the initial state of "state"

Comment: I have moved it after Initialize, but the label still does not update. Also, if I want to have this label update as the variable updates, will this work? Or do i need to add something?

Comment: Ah, i see. Got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can get rid of the TestObject alltogether and use the control itself as a DataContext to get a shorter solution.

Comment: @CShark, sorry could you elaborate?

Comment: You can add the INotify Interface to the userControl instead to the new class and move all of the code in TestObject to your userControl. Then you can set the DataContext to 'this' instead of the TestObject instance.

Comment: Got it. thanks again. One last thing... I need to update the `State` variable from another thread. Can I bind this in a way that it will update when the other thread does? Or do i need to write a new thread that `'listens' for changes?

Comment: State will now tell the Gui whenever it changes. Regarding threadsafety; I only know that Dependency properties won't play well with threading. I never tested INotify in that regard. If it does not work you can use the Dispatcher to change the variable from the main thread while staying in your seperate thread.

Comment: Thank you again for your time. Much appreciated.